# Is there a reason to eat beef instead of pork?

Tags: sharia, food, life, pork

Allah sais that eating beef is allowed, and eating swine is forbidden. I have studied the medical science of beef and swine, and I found that 10 times more people die of cow tuberculosis and other beef-related problems than from pork.

Only 1 person dies from pig meat infection every 10 years in Europe, and hundreds die from beef tuberculosis and E-coli.

It says that 5 million people die every year from smoking, 3 million die from being fat, 3 million people die from animal fat from eating beef, pork, lamb and birds, 2 million die from sexually transmitted diseases, 2 million die from alcohol, 1 million babies die from lack of breast milk, 1 million people die because they are missing fruit and healthy food, but only 2 people in rich countries die every 10 years from eating pork, and 100ds die every year from beef, because beef can carry E-Coli bacteria and tuberculosis. Worldwide, 20,000 people die every year from eating meat, but only 50-150 people die from eating pork.

Why does Allah say that pork is forbidden, and it is Ok to eat animal fat and beef, if pork kills a thousand times less people than animal fat, and less than beef?

Answer (score 1):

No one can know for sure why Allah forbids this and allows this except if He tells us.

There is no such explanation by Allah for why pork is forbidden or beef is allowed. As Muslims, we follow the commands of Allah. And Allah knows best.

Allah says:

> It is not for a believing man or a believing woman, when Allah and His Messenger have decided a matter, that they should [thereafter] have any choice about their affair. And whoever disobeys Allah and His Messenger has certainly strayed into clear error. (33:36)